# Endpoints quickstart-app-engine for Python deploy error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to following the step-by-step tutorial found [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-app-engine), but the deploy just does not work, always returning `Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred`.

I did not change anything in the example code itself. As I said, I just followed the linked tutorial carefully. It fails and return the error above when I try `gcloud app deploy`.

Using `gcloud app deploy --verbosity debug` it brings some stacktrace, but without any usefull meaning. I'm copying below for completeness:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 791, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 756, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 65, in Run
    parallel_build=False)
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 587, in RunDeploy
    flex_image_build_option=flex_image_build_option)
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 395, in Deploy
    extra_config_settings)
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 188, in DeployService
    message=message)
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 244, in WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=retry_interval)
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 266, in WaitFor
    sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 222, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 260, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "/Users/jamesmiranda/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 169, in IsDone
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(operation.error)))
OperationError: Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred
```

Below is the app.yaml (exactly tha same of example git, except for the APPID):

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

# [START configuration]
endpoints_api_service:
  # The following values are to be replaced by information from the output of
  # 'gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-appengine.yaml' command.
  name:  echo-api.endpoints.MYAPPID.cloud.goog
  config_id: [2018-01-09r1]
 # [END configuration]
```

What I tried until now:

- Change python version to python 2 (python_version: 2);
- Include some files to skip in the app.yaml (copied from endpoint framework in standard env [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python));

  `skip_files:`

  `- ^(.*/)?#.*#$`

  `- ^(.*/)?.*~$`

  `- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$`

  `- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$`

  `- ^(.*/)?\..*$`

  `- ^(.*/)?setuptools/script \(dev\).tmpl$`
- Tried the workaround from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/281#issuecomment-327572081);

  gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True

NOthing worked. What I'm doing wrong?

Notes:

- It works fine locally following the [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/getting-started/README.md) info;
- Everything works in GAE standard env folowing [this another tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python);
- I did not found any problem in the Endpoint itself (I can see it deployed in API explorer), but the app deploy did not work in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app.yaml file you are using is exactly the same as the one you copied in your question then there seems to be an error in the name and config-id you are entering. With the info provided in your question your app.yaml should look like:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

# [START configuration]
endpoints_api_service:
  # The following values are to be replaced by information from the output of
  # 'gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-appengine.yaml' command.
  name:  "echo-api.endpoints.MYAPPID.cloud.goog"
  config_id: "2018-01-09r1"
 # [END configuration]
```

See that you were not entering the values for name and config_id inside quotation marks, and also you should not enter your config_id inside brackets.

I have tried this myself and works alright. If it still doesn't work for you maybe your name is not correct, as the format seems to be:

- "example-project.appspot.com"

So if your project id is i.e. my-project-id, then your name would look like:

```
"my-project-id.appspot.com"
```

Comment: A typo? Shame on me. Apparently, it's all working fine now.